# swift stack install fails due to ssl certificate mismatch

Tags: centos, cloud, openstack, pypi, openstack-swift

I am attempting to install the swift stack, but it fails because of an ssl verification error:

```
 [root @ localhost ~] # wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.9.8.tar.gz
- 2013-12-11 11:30:32 p.m. - https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.9.8.tar.gz
Resolution pypi.python.org ... 185.31.17.184, 185.31.17.185
Login to pypi.python.org | 185.31.17.184 |: 443 ... connected.
ERROR: The common name ". * A.ssl.fastly.net" certificate does not match the name of the host requested "pypi.python.org."
To connect to unsecured pypi.python.org, use `- no-check-certificate '.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please follow SAIO guide it will be helpful http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html in installing OpenStack Swift.

Hope it helps.